# How to Implement scrollIntoView in a horizontal view table for testimony

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm sorry maybe the title make you confused, but it exactly what the title said **I want to make a testimony card using table as based** but I almost finish it but i can't do the final touch for it, let say I have a pointer so when I click the pointer the card will swipe to the next card but it seems I'm confused as how to implement it using javascript. I get a hunch that I can use array of child for it and move in based on the index but the card testimony still won't move

I read some topic, but the near to what I want is answer in here: [Scroll smoothly by 100px horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54794261/scroll-smoothly-by-100px-horizontally)

but I confused as how to implement it.

this is my code:

```js
            var slideIndex = 1;
            showSlides(slideIndex);

            // Thumbnail image controls
            function currentTestimony(n) {
                showSlides(slideIndex = n);
            }

            function showSlides(n) {
                var i;
                var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slider-item");
                var pointers = document.getElementsByClassName("pointer");
                if (n > slides.length) {
                    slideIndex = 1
                }

                if (n < 1) {
                    slideIndex = slides.length
                }
                
//                for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
//                    slides[i].getElementsById('testimony-3').scrollIntoView()
//                }

                for (i = 0; i < pointers.length; i++) {
                    pointers[i].className = pointers[i].className.replace(" active", "");
                }

                pointers[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
            }
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito&display=swap');

#dark-slider-testimonial .card{
    background-color: #f5f7fb;
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 380px;
    height: 380px;
    margin: 0% 32px;
    padding: 20px;
    display: inline-table;
}

/* 
    ===================================================================
    First Table
    ===================================================================
*/
#dark-slider-testimonial {
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 5%;
    width: 100%;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#dark-slider-testimonial .container{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
    scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}

#dark-slider-testimonial .container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
    background: transparent;
}

#dark-slider-testimonial table {
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: #1d3962;
    border: none;
    border-top: none;
}

#dark-slider-testimonial tr{
    text-align: left;
}

#dark-slider-testimonial td{
    text-align: left;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
}

#dark-slider-testimonial .testimony-name{
    font-size: 1.6em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #1D3962;
    line-height: 1.7em;
}

#dark-slider-testimonial .testimony-title{
    font-size: 1.4em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #1D3962;
    line-height: 1.7em;
}

#dark-slider-testimonial .testimony-subtitle{
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #7E94B3;
    line-height: 1.7em;
}

#dark-slider-testimonial .testimony-desc{
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #1D3962;
    line-height: 1.7em;
}

#dark-slider-testimonial .pointer {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

#dark-slider-testimonial .active,
#dark-slider-testimonial .pointer:hover {
    background-color: #3b73c5;
}
```

```html
        <div id="dark-slider-testimonial">
            <div>
                <div class="container">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td id="testimony-1" class="slider-item">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <p class="testimony-name">
                                        name
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="testimony-subtitle">
                                        title
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="testimony-desc">
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur eveniet harum aperiam autem ab modi, impedit culpa, obcaecati repellendus ipsa nulla repudiandae, illo consequatur. Eum fugiat explicabo voluptas numquam doloremque.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </td>

                            <td id="testimony-2" class="slider-item">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <p class="testimony-name">
                                        name
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="testimony-subtitle">
                                        title
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="testimony-desc">
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur eveniet harum aperiam autem ab modi, impedit culpa, obcaecati repellendus ipsa nulla repudiandae, illo consequatur. Eum fugiat explicabo voluptas numquam doloremque.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </td>

                            <td id="testimony-3" class="slider-item">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <p class="testimony-name">
                                        name
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="testimony-subtitle">
                                        title
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="testimony-desc">
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur eveniet harum aperiam autem ab modi, impedit culpa, obcaecati repellendus ipsa nulla repudiandae, illo consequatur. Eum fugiat explicabo voluptas numquam doloremque.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </td>

                            <td id="testimony-4" class="slider-item">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <p class="testimony-name">
                                        name
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="testimony-subtitle">
                                        title
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="testimony-desc">
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur eveniet harum aperiam autem ab modi, impedit culpa, obcaecati repellendus ipsa nulla repudiandae, illo consequatur. Eum fugiat explicabo voluptas numquam doloremque.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </td>

                            <td id="testimony-5" class="slider-item">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <p class="testimony-name">
                                        name
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="testimony-subtitle">
                                        title
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="testimony-desc">
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur eveniet harum aperiam autem ab modi, impedit culpa, obcaecati repellendus ipsa nulla repudiandae, illo consequatur. Eum fugiat explicabo voluptas numquam doloremque.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>

                <!-- The pointers/circles -->
                <div style="text-align:center">
                    <span class="pointer" onclick="currentTestimony(1)"></span>
                    <span class="pointer" onclick="currentTestimony(2)"></span>
                    <span class="pointer" onclick="currentTestimony(3)"></span>
                    <span class="pointer" onclick="currentTestimony(4)"></span>
                    <span class="pointer" onclick="currentTestimony(5)"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I feel I'm already near the answer but I can't quite know how to solved this, can someone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: You want only 1 Testimoney to display at a time? And then slide them using the pointers?

Comment: @MosiaThabo thankyou for your response, not only 1 I want display the rest of testimony but `n-1` , maybe the right way to say it "I want the testimony I click or choose appear in the left" so it make like this `n`, `n+1`, `n+2` but only `n-i` that won't appear, you can try it but slide the card to the right 1 time and thats what I want to achieve with the pointer

Comment: Ok I understand now. Let me have a look quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is this It?**

I have illustrated the code I've added and removed in your stylesheet. And the entire Javascript has also changed. But it's all straight forward.

```js
var PositionPerIndex = {
  "1": "0",
  "2": "-20%",
  "3": "-40%",
  "4": "-60%",
  "5": "-80%"
};

document.querySelectorAll(".pointer").forEach(
  function(pointer){
    pointer.addEventListener('click', 
      function(){
        document.getElementById("content").style.left = PositionPerIndex[this.getAttribute("data-index")];
      }
    );
  }
);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito&display=swap');

#dark-slider-testimonial .card{
    background-color: #f5f7fb;
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 380px;
    height: 380px;
    margin: 0% 32px;
    padding: 20px;
    display: inline-table;
}

/* 
    ===================================================================
    First Table
    ===================================================================
*/
#dark-slider-testimonial {
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 5%;
    width: 100%;
    /* START Removed 
        scroll-behavior: smooth;
       END
     */
     
    /* START Added */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#dark-slider-testimonial .container{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    
    /* START Removed 
        overflow-x: auto;
        scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
       END
     */
     
    /* START Added */
    overflow: hidden;
}

#dark-slider-testimonial .container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
    background: transparent;
}

#dark-slider-testimonial table {
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: #1d3962;
    border: none;
    border-top: none;
}

#dark-slider-testimonial tr{
    text-align: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    
    /* Added this */
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    left: 0%;
    transition: left .5s ease;
}

#dark-slider-testimonial td{
    text-align: left;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    
    /* Added this */
    flex-basis: 20%;
}

#dark-slider-testimonial .testimony-name{
    font-size: 1.6em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #1D3962;
    line-height: 1.7em;
}

#dark-slider-testimonial .testimony-title{
    font-size: 1.4em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #1D3962;
    line-height: 1.7em;
}

#dark-slider-testimonial .testimony-subtitle{
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #7E94B3;
    line-height: 1.7em;
}

#dark-slider-testimonial .testimony-desc{
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #1D3962;
    line-height: 1.7em;
}

#dark-slider-testimonial .pointer {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

#dark-slider-testimonial .active,
#dark-slider-testimonial .pointer:hover {
    background-color: #3b73c5;
}
```

```html
<div id="dark-slider-testimonial">
            <div>
                <div class="container">
                    <table>
                        <tr id="content">
                            <td id="testimony-1" class="slider-item">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <p class="testimony-name">
                                        name
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="testimony-subtitle">
                                        title
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="testimony-desc">
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur eveniet harum aperiam autem ab modi, impedit culpa, obcaecati repellendus ipsa nulla repudiandae, illo consequatur. Eum fugiat explicabo voluptas numquam doloremque.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </td>

                            <td id="testimony-2" class="slider-item">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <p class="testimony-name">
                                        name
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="testimony-subtitle">
                                        title
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="testimony-desc">
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur eveniet harum aperiam autem ab modi, impedit culpa, obcaecati repellendus ipsa nulla repudiandae, illo consequatur. Eum fugiat explicabo voluptas numquam doloremque.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </td>

                            <td id="testimony-3" class="slider-item">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <p class="testimony-name">
                                        name
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="testimony-subtitle">
                                        title
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="testimony-desc">
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur eveniet harum aperiam autem ab modi, impedit culpa, obcaecati repellendus ipsa nulla repudiandae, illo consequatur. Eum fugiat explicabo voluptas numquam doloremque.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </td>

                            <td id="testimony-4" class="slider-item">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <p class="testimony-name">
                                        name
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="testimony-subtitle">
                                        title
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="testimony-desc">
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur eveniet harum aperiam autem ab modi, impedit culpa, obcaecati repellendus ipsa nulla repudiandae, illo consequatur. Eum fugiat explicabo voluptas numquam doloremque.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </td>

                            <td id="testimony-5" class="slider-item">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <p class="testimony-name">
                                        name
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="testimony-subtitle">
                                        title
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="testimony-desc">
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur eveniet harum aperiam autem ab modi, impedit culpa, obcaecati repellendus ipsa nulla repudiandae, illo consequatur. Eum fugiat explicabo voluptas numquam doloremque.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>

                <!-- The pointers/circles -->
                <div style="text-align:center">
                    <span class="pointer" data-index="1"></span>
                    <span class="pointer" data-index="2"></span>
                    <span class="pointer" data-index="3"></span>
                    <span class="pointer" data-index="4"></span>
                    <span class="pointer" data-index="5"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Wow Thankyou, yes it is like you make above, you really save me here once again thank you. But can I ask some question? first what if I have more than 5 card? must I define the position first? is there any way to make it more dynamic?

Comment: Let me make another Answer that is more universal, that would take n number of Cards.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more Universal Answer that works on a fixed size. You can just change sizing into percentage to make it work for different screen sizes.

I've worked it out on VS Code. You can just copy and paste it and run.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <style>
            *{
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }

            .main-container {
                width: 100%;
                max-width: 1200px;
                overflow: hidden;
                margin: 0 auto;
                margin-bottom: 20px;
            }

            table.card-space{
                width: 100%;
                height: auto;
                min-height: 400px;
                position: relative;
                white-space: nowrap;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            tr.card-space_container{
                width: 100%;
                left: 0; /* Initial Position */
                position: relative;

                /* Make a Smooth Left Transition */
                transition: left .5s ease;
                padding: 15px;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            td.card{
                box-sizing: border-box;
                margin: 0;
                width: 400px;
                min-height: 390px;
                margin: 0;
                position: relative;
            }

            .card-space .card .content{
                width: 400px;
                min-height: 100%;
                background-color: #f5f5f5;
                min-height: 390px;
                padding: 15px;
            }

            .pointer-space{
                text-align: center;

                width: 100%;
                max-width: 1200px;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }

            .pointer-space .pointer {
                cursor: pointer;
                height: 15px;
                width: 15px;
                margin: 0 2px;
                background-color: #bbb;
                border-radius: 50%;
                display: inline-block;
                transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
            }

            .pointer-space .pointer:hover {
                background-color: #3b73c5;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main-container">
            <table class="card-space">
                <tr class="card-space_container" id="card-space_container">
                    <td class="card">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h1>Card1</h1>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="card">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h1>Card2</h1>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="card">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h1>Card3</h1>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="card">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h1>Card4</h1>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="card">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h1>Card5</h1>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="card">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h1>Card6</h1>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <!-- The pointers/circles -->
        <div class="pointer-space">
        <span class="pointer" data-index="0"></span>
        <span class="pointer" data-index="1"></span>
        <span class="pointer" data-index="2"></span>
        <span class="pointer" data-index="3"></span>
        <span class="pointer" data-index="4"></span>
        <span class="pointer" data-index="5"></span>
        </div>

        <script>
        (function(){
            // Get all the Pointers
            var PointerList = document.querySelectorAll(".pointer");

            //  Get the Card container
            var container = document.getElementById("card-space_container");

            PointerList.forEach(function(pointer){
                pointer.addEventListener('click', function(){

                    //  First get the index represented by each pointer
                    var i = this.getAttribute('data-index');

                    //  Summary:
                    //      Then Calculate the position to which card-space_container must be set.
                    //  examples:   
                    //      -If the index returned by a pointer is 0, then 0 x -40 = 0; so the position is set to 0px.
                    //      -If the pointer return index as 1, then 1  x -400 = -400%;
                    //      - etc...
                    container.style.left = (i * (-400)).toString().concat('px');
                });
            });
        })();
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```